# Where can I get a case that is also a battery for the iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone

I have seen ones for previous versions of the iPhone - is there one for the new iPhone though?

Answer (score 3):

Not yet, but I found a couple that are soon to be released:

- [iPhone 4 Fuel Max](http://www.case-mate.com/iPhone-4-Cases/Case-Mate-iPhone-4-Fuel-Max.asp)
- [EXOGEAR iPhone Battery Case](http://www.exogear.com/products-iphone-4.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've been very pleased with my [mophie](http://www.mophie.com/) "juice pack" for my first-generation iPhone and the "juice pack air" for my 3GS.  I recommend waiting for mophie to ship a battery case for the iPhone 4.  You probably won't have to wait very long—I'm sure they're eager to tap the already large and fast-growing market of iPhone 4 owners.